# Alternating editText text color onButtonClick

Tags: java, android, button

I am currently trying to create a highlighter function for my app where on a button being clicked by the user the program checks to see if the editText TextColor is black, default, or Yellow, highlighted, then switches between the two.

I am using an onClickListener if Statement:

```
        hB0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (ed1.getTextColors().equals(Color.BLACK)){
                ed1.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            } else {
                ed1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
    });
```

I have set the textColor of the EditText to Color.Black in the XML file and I have looked for similar problems with little to show for it! Thank you for your time.

Edit: The problem is when I press the button the text stays the same colour and doesn't switch between the two.

Edit2: To take it further, when I comment out the if statement and make the button simply change the text colour to Color.YELLOW it works perfectly. I just want to be able to switch the colour BACK to black.

Edit 3: The XML Code for the highlighter button and the textView I want to change the text color in.

```
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/highLighter0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
            android:minWidth="4dp"
            android:minHeight="10dp"
            android:text="H"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/slot0"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/slot0"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/slot0" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/slot0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="6 AM"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
            android:lines="4"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:rotationX="0"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/highLighter0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shoppingListButton"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="45dp"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="370dp" />
```

EditText @id=slot0 is ed1 in the java code.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Sorry I should have realized I didnt mention that. When I press the button nothing happens. The text stays black but my app doesn't crash.

Comment: did you set break point inside onlick and if statemrnt if you your code flow is coming inside on click event?

Comment: can you show xml and java code

Comment: The if statement isn't a loop though, do I need to set a break for the code? I thought it would just work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code with below code:

```
 if (ed1.getCurrentTextColor() == Color.BLACK) {
     ed1.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
  } else {
       ed1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
  }
```